# Как добавить '0' к строке если одна из перемених равна 0?

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, функции, методы

Незнаю как вставить '0' к строке если одна из перемених равна 0;

```
function colorOf(r,g,b){
    let a = r.toString(16);
    let c = g.toString(16);
    let d = b.toString(16);

      return '#'+a+c+d;
   }
```

Должно получитса  `#ff0000`  а получаеться `#ff00`

Comment: Добавить спереди ноль, взять 2 последних символа.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `padStart`:

```js
function colorOf(r, g, b) {
  return '#' + [r, g, b].map(c => c.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
}

console.log(colorOf(255, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function colorOf(r,g,b){
    let a = r.toString(16);
    let c = g.toString(16);
    let d = b.toString(16);

    if (r < 16){a = 0 + a;} 
    if (g < 16){c = 0 + c;}  
    if (b < 16){d= 0 + d;} 
      return '#'+a+c+d;
   }
```